# Losing leading "0" when assigning values?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code snippet:

```
Sheets("Output").range(rng.Value).NumberFormat = "##0_)"

Sheets("Output").range(rng.Value).Value = _
Sheets("Input").range(rng.Offset(0,1).Value).Value
```

However, if I have a number like 01234 in the source cell, when it writes it to the Output cell Excel is dropping the leading zero. How do I make it keep the zero? FYI I need that number format in the first line to stop Excel writing long values as exponentials.

Comment: Assigning a number format (which you already do) is already enough to " stop Excel writing long values as exponentials".

Comment: Thanks that's good to know, I still need a way to stop the leading zeroes being dropped though

Comment: You either need to format as text, or specify the leading zeroes in the number format code if there's a fixed number of digits.

Comment: Thank you that worked, using NumberFormat "@".